# Why overflow-hidden in tailwind css still appear in front of other element

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I created a simple images layout with transform. I've added overflow-hidden class to the parent div but the scaled image overflow still appear in front of the above image. How to prevent the overflow image from appearing in front of the above image?

[image]

```
<div class="flex" style="height: 50vh">
        <a href="#" class="flex-1 bg-gray-400 relative overflow-hidden">
            <img class="object-cover origin-center h-full w-full hover:opacity-75 transition ease-in-out duration-150 hover:scale-110 transform" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519638399535-1b036603ac77?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1189&amp;q=80" alt="">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="flex-1 bg-gray-400  overflow-hidden">
            <img class="object-cover h-full w-full hover:opacity-75 transition ease-in-out duration-150 hover:scale-110 transform" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1569701813229-33284b643e3c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=500&amp;q=60" alt="">
        </a>
        <div class="flex-1 bg-gray-400 relative overflow-hidden">
            <a href="#" class="w-1/4 bg-gray-400 overflow-hidden relative">
                <img class="object-cover w-full hover:opacity-75 transition ease-in-out duration-150 hover:scale-110 transform" style="height: 50%" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1569701813229-33284b643e3c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=500&amp;q=60" alt="">
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="w-1/4 bg-gray-400 overflow-hidden">
                <img class="object-cover w-full hover:opacity-75 transition ease-in-out duration-150 hover:scale-110 origin-center transform" style="height: 50%" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1569701813229-33284b643e3c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=500&amp;q=60" alt="">
            </a>

        </div>
        <div class="flex-1 bg-gray-400 overflow-hidden">
            <a href="#" class="w-1/4 bg-gray-400 overflow-hidden">
                <img class="object-cover w-full hover:opacity-75 transition ease-in-out duration-150 hover:scale-110 transform" style="height: 50%" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1569701813229-33284b643e3c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=500&amp;q=60" alt="">
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="w-1/4 bg-gray-400 overflow-hidden">
                <img class="object-cover w-full hover:opacity-75 transition ease-in-out duration-150 hover:scale-110 transform" style="height: 50%" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1569701813229-33284b643e3c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=500&amp;q=60" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Try to use zIndex...

Comment: @mkEagles could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of problems here.

1. "overflow: hidden" will not work on inline elements, but "a" tag is inline.
2. You are using width and height on this inline elements (and you should not).
3. You do not need to use relative with overflow unless child will be positioned absolutely.
4. Instead of style="height: 50%" it would be better to also using tailwind (h-1/2).
5. But you do not need 50% height on element, just set flex and flex-col on parent.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="flex" style="height: 50vh">
  <a href="#" class="flex-1 block bg-gray-400 overflow-hidden">
    <img class="object-cover origin-center h-full w-full hover:opacity-75 transition ease-in-out duration-150 hover:scale-110 transform" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519638399535-1b036603ac77?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1189&amp;q=80" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="flex-1 block bg-gray-400 overflow-hidden">
    <img class="object-cover h-full w-full hover:opacity-75 transition ease-in-out duration-150 hover:scale-110 transform" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1569701813229-33284b643e3c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=500&amp;q=60" alt="">
  </a>
  <div class="flex-1 flex flex-col bg-gray-400 overflow-hidden">
    <a href="#" class="block bg-gray-400 overflow-hidden">
      <img class="object-cover w-full h-full hover:opacity-75 transition ease-in-out duration-150 hover:scale-110 transform" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1569701813229-33284b643e3c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=500&amp;q=60" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="block bg-gray-400 overflow-hidden">
      <img class="object-cover w-full h-full hover:opacity-75 transition ease-in-out duration-150 hover:scale-110 transform" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1569701813229-33284b643e3c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=500&amp;q=60" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-1 flex flex-col bg-gray-400 relative overflow-hidden">
    <a href="#" class="block bg-gray-400 overflow-hidden">
      <img class="object-cover w-full h-full hover:opacity-75 transition ease-in-out duration-150 hover:scale-110 transform" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1569701813229-33284b643e3c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=500&amp;q=60" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="block bg-gray-400  overflow-hidden">
      <img class="object-cover w-full h-full hover:opacity-75 transition ease-in-out duration-150 hover:scale-110 transform" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1569701813229-33284b643e3c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=500&amp;q=60" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, this template looks like perfect example of grid css utility. So You can also use grids like this instead of flexboxes:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="grid grid-cols-4 grid-rows-2" style="height: 50vh">
  <a href="#" class="col-span-1 row-span-2 block bg-gray-400 overflow-hidden">
    <img class="object-cover origin-center h-full w-full hover:opacity-75 transition ease-in-out duration-150 hover:scale-110 transform" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519638399535-1b036603ac77?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1189&amp;q=80" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="col-span-1 row-span-2  block bg-gray-400 overflow-hidden">
    <img class="object-cover h-full w-full hover:opacity-75 transition ease-in-out duration-150 hover:scale-110 transform" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1569701813229-33284b643e3c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=500&amp;q=60" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="col-span-1 block bg-gray-400 overflow-hidden">
    <img class="object-cover w-full h-full hover:opacity-75 transition ease-in-out duration-150 hover:scale-110 transform" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1569701813229-33284b643e3c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=500&amp;q=60" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="col-span-1 block bg-gray-400 overflow-hidden">
    <img class="object-cover w-full h-full hover:opacity-75 transition ease-in-out duration-150 hover:scale-110 transform" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1569701813229-33284b643e3c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=500&amp;q=60" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="col-span-1 block bg-gray-400 overflow-hidden">
    <img class="object-cover w-full h-full hover:opacity-75 transition ease-in-out duration-150 hover:scale-110 transform" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1569701813229-33284b643e3c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=500&amp;q=60" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="col-span-1 block bg-gray-400 overflow-hidden">
    <img class="object-cover w-full h-full hover:opacity-75 transition ease-in-out duration-150 hover:scale-110 transform" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1569701813229-33284b643e3c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=500&amp;q=60" alt="">
  </a>  
</div>
```